# Error en la vista: Undefined variable $org

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero registrar un usuario y quiero llenar ese select desde la BD. Comparto el código.

Controlador, acá estoy llamando al modelo de organización

```php
public function create()
    {
        $org = Organizacion::all();
        $idio = Idioma::all();
        return view('auth.register', compact('org', 'idio'));
    }
```

Esta es la Vista de la parte del select

```html
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="organizacions" class="label">{{ __('Organizacion') }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select name="organizacion" id="organizacion" class="form-control form-control-line" value="{{ old('organizacion') }}" required autocomplete="organizacion" autofocus>
           @foreach ($org as $organizacion)
            <option value="{{ $organizacion->id }}">{{ $organizacion->nombre}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
```

Route.Web

```php
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/auth/register', 'RegisterController@create');
Auth::routes();
Route::post('/auth/register', 'RegisterController@store');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre evalúa que traen tus variables, eso es depurar el código, comenta la vista y mira lo que trae **$org**

```
public function create()
{
   $org = Organizacion::all();
   $idio = Idioma::all();
   // return view('auth.register', compact('org', 'idio'));
   dd($org);
}
```

Averigua sobre **dd**;

Answer (score 0):

Cuando obtienes tus registros a través del método estático `Model::all()` Laravel convierte tus registros en un array, por tanto la forma correcta de acceder a ellos sería:

```
$organizacion['id'];
$organizacion['nombre'];

//Esto produce un warning y no lee la variable
$organizacion->id;
$organizacion->nombre;
```

Cambia el código de tu plantilla a este:

```
<div class="form-group" >
    <label for="organizacions" class="label">{{ __('Organizacion') }}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select name="organizacion" id="organizacion" class="form-control form-control-line" value="{{ old('organizacion') }}" required autocomplete="organizacion" autofocus>
        @foreach ($org as $organizacion)
            <option value="{{ $organizacion['id'] }}">{{ $organizacion['nombre']}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```